# Declare a type with unused type function argument

Tags: haskell

By 'type function argument' I mean this

```
> newtype Wrapper f a = Wrapper (f a)
> :kind Wrapper
Wrapper :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

So `f` here is a type function argument, so I can construct type like this

```
> :kind Wrapper Maybe Int
Wrapper Maybe Int :: *
```

Now the problem for me is that I actually use `f` in the value of `Wrapper`, and I want to ignore it:

```
> newtype Wrapper f a = Wrapper a
> :kind Wrapper
Wrapper :: * -> * -> *
```

Guess what! `f` is no longer a type function and causes my previous type construction to fail:

```
> :kind Wrapper Maybe Int
<interactive>:1:9: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Maybe’
      Expected a type, but ‘Maybe’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the first argument of ‘Wrapper’, namely ‘Maybe’
      In the type ‘Wrapper Maybe Int’
```

So how can I construct type same way (`Wrapper Maybe Int`) without the need to have concrete `Maybe` value inside my `Wrapper` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I just need to use language extension:

```
> {-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

> newtype Wrapper (f :: * -> *) a = Wrapper a

> :kind Wrapper
Wrapper :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

Comment: You can also enable `PolyKinds`, then `Wrapper` becomes kind-polymorphic in `f`.